# Ruby on Rails: Pushing to heroku - keys error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, key

I have recently moved my app from a linux machine to windows, and I am trying to set it up with heroku again. There are problems with my keys, so I am just wanting to push the app up as a brand new app.

I do, `git init`, then `git add .`, then `git commit -m "init"`, and now I do `heroku create`.

I want to just push my folder up to the new app cedar, but everytime I run `git push heroku master` is tries to push to the old one, and an error flags as my keys don't match.

Anyone have any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute `heroku auth:logout` to logout, then `heroku auth:login` to login again.

To read full help message, try

```
heroku help
heroku auth
```

Comment: I did as you said, and followed the commands I have in my question, and again I got. ` !  Your key with fingerprint XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX is not authorized to access old_app_name.`

Comment: Are you sure the account you logged in has the permission to access the project? or do you have a different account?

Comment: I have managed to fix it. By removing all keys from my system, and heroku. Generating new ones, and also running this command, `git remote rm heroku`

Comment: Strangely, I happened to have this problem with Git on OSX the other day, stopped me from pushing to GitHub and Heroku, had to re-generate my keys.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're calling `heroku apps:create` wrongly? Take a look at the documentation [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/creating-apps).

Also, the [deployment documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/deployment) might be more useful for you if you already have a git repository setup.

Comment: I had a read of the docs you linked and tried, `$ heroku git:clone -a myapp` and I got the same error I have been getting. ` `!  Your key with fingerprint 48:9d:cc:9f:99:03:02:a3:72:a9:a5:d5:51:b3:0c:85 is not authorized to access old_app_name.`